# Clean Python Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, list

Is there a cleaner way to write long regex patterns in python? I saw this approach somewhere but regex in python doesn't allow lists.

```
patterns = [
    re.compile(r'<!--([^->]|(-+[^->])|(-?>))*-{2,}>'),
    re.compile(r'\n+|\s{2}')
]
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use verbose mode to write more readable regular expressions. In this mode:

- Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when in a character class or preceded by an unescaped backslash.
- When a line contains a '#' neither in a character class or preceded by an unescaped backslash, all characters from the leftmost such '#' through the end of the line are ignored.

The following two statements are equivalent:

```
a = re.compile(r"""\d +  # the integral part
                   \.    # the decimal point
                   \d *  # some fractional digits""", re.X)

b = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d*")
```

(Taken from the documentation of [verbose mode](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE))

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that it's the "re.X" that means verbose mode which is equivalent to writing "re.VERBOSE".

Answer (score 13):

Though @Ayman's suggestion about `re.VERBOSE` is a better idea, if all you want is what you're showing, just do:

```
patterns = re.compile(
        r'<!--([^->]|(-+[^->])|(-?>))*-{2,}>'
        r'\n+|\s{2}'
)
```

and Python's automatic concatenation of adjacent string literals (much like C's, btw) will do the rest;-).

Comment: this would be Python's auto-concatenation COMBINED with Python's auto line-joining between brackets and parens.

Answer (score 2):

You can use comments in regex's, which make them much more readable.  Taking an example from http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html :

```
/               # identify URLs within a text file
          [^="] # do not match URLs in IMG tags like:
                # <img src="http://mysite.com/mypic.png">
http|ftp|gopher # make sure we find a resource type
          :\/\/ # ...needs to be followed by colon-slash-slash
      [^ \n\r]+ # stuff other than space, newline, tab is in URL
    (?=[\s\.,]) # assert: followed by whitespace/period/comma 
/
```

Comment: ...as long as you compile them with re.VERBOSE, per Ayman's suggestion.